# How to explain an unofficial research sabbatical on my CV?

Tags: cv, sabbatical

Last year, I took 3 months off my usual paid work (in an partly related field) and just focused on research.  Although, I remained as an Adjunct for a university, this 'research sabbatical' was an unofficial and a personal decision. During that time, I was able to publish and submit several papers.

However, this leaves a noticeable gap in my usual work history of 'some related job + Adjunct'.  At this stage, the sabbatical is only 'covered' on the CV by the Adjunct position and does not seem enough of an explanation, as it does not seem to emphasise the research output I was able to achieve.  (please note - my concern is not the paid vs unpaid aspect of my work history).

I would like to indicate that I went on an unofficial sabbatical on the CV with particular emphasis on the research output, but are not sure how.

**How can I explain an unofficial 'research sabbatical' on a CV?**

Comment: You could make a brief mention in the CV and then give a more complete explanation in a cover letter. Also note that a three-month gap is so short that you could also just not mention it -- unless you feel that mentioning it makes you more attractive.  You might want to let your publication list speak for itself.

Answer (score 3):

Given that it sounds like the university was aware of your plans to come back and seems to have kept your original faculty position for you while you were on sabbatical, you don't have to list this as separate employment. Sabbaticals are well understood within the academic field; listing it separately is just confusing things.

You may want to put the sabbatical as a sub-bullet under your academic position on your resume just to emphasize that (1) you're a cool enough person that your university allowed you to take sabbatical (and held your position for you until you came back), and (2) you have experience doing research outside the university setting.